# Swift Firebase Facebook login GET requests should contain an explicit "fields" parameter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-login, swift5

I'm using Facebook login with Firebase and I'm getting this error: 
`FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /222413188829898/model_asset should contain an explicit "fields" parameter`

This is how I create the button view:

I have seen some answers in JavaScript SDK but I do not know how to fix this in Swift because I'm not doing any GET requests (directly).

```
struct FacebookLoginButtonView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookLoginButtonView>) -> FBLoginButton {
        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookLoginButtonView>) {
        //
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {

        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            if error != nil {
                // print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let currentAccessToken = AccessToken.current {
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: currentAccessToken.tokenString)

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: AuthService(firestoreService: FirestoreService()).snHandler)
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your issue, but according to the documentation found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login . The required FB button class is actually FBSDKLoginButton. Same thing applies for the other classes like FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult etc.

Comment: 'FBSDKLoginButton' has been renamed to 'FBLoginButton' but they didn't update the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have docs about [Swift implementation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios)

I think your problem is caused by a missing permissions
`loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]`

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with iOS FBSDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1387